# ipyparallel error when using decorator

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to run a job using the ipyparallel system with `lru_cache` and am running into issues.

From the terminal:

```
ipcluster start -n 2
```

In an ipython notebook:

```
from ipyparallel import Client
clients = Client()

def world():
    return hello() + " World"

def hello():
    return "Hello"

world()
'Hello World'
```

Running it with ipyparallel requires this:

```
clients[:].push(dict(hello=hello))
```

Without the previous line the following fails, which is not unexpected, but works fine if it is run:

```
clients[:].apply_sync(world)
['Hello World', 'Hello World']
```

This all works as expected, however, with the `lru_cache` the parallel step generates errors

```
from ipyparallel import Client
from functools import lru_cache

clients = Client()

def world():
    return hello() + " World"

@lru_cache(maxsize=2048)
def hello():
    return "Hello"

clients[:].push(dict(hello=hello))
clients[:].apply_sync(world)
```

This fails with the following error:

```
  [0:apply]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()
<ipython-input-17-9ac5ef032485> in world()
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

[1:apply]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()
<ipython-input-17-9ac5ef032485> in world()
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

I realize this may be a namespace issue where `lru_cache` is using a closure, however I'm hoping there is a workaround so that I am able to use it. Or if someone can tell me that this simply isn't possible that would be useful as well, thanks.

I am using:
ipykernel (4.1.1)
ipyparallel (4.1.0)
ipython (4.0.1)
Python (3.5.1)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the decorator itself. If you replace `lru_cache` with any other decorator function you will have the same error. I don't know if it can be solved though..

Comment: Thanks, @imaluengo that was my initial thought as well, though I was able to get it working with other decorators. I debated about including an example with a working decorator in the original post though it was getting to be quite a long post.

Comment: Ops, I tried with a test decorator in python 2.7 and it didn't work for me :/